# ASP.NET Creating a mobile site

Tags: asp.net, css, mobile

I have finished creating my site which works great in normal PC browsers. However I now need to style the site to work with mobile phones. Does anyone know what the best way to do this is? Is it to just use separate style sheets for mobile devices or do I use a different domain altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think using MVC design pattern is going to be the best bet.  You use the same models for your business logic and just deliver a different view for the mobile device.

The problem with restyling for mobile is that the best user experience on a mobile device often involves changing the overall design concept, not just restyling the existing page.  People use mobile devices differently than a standard web page and your design should allow for this.

Comment: Good point but the design has nothing to do with how the site is "implemented". He could just as easily use Web Forms... +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it mobile friendly by recognizing the client browser and redirect him to the appropriate version of the website. 
[Have a look at this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EasyStepsToAMobilefriendlyResponsiveDesignWithAnEmbeddedYouTubeVideoAndAFluidResize.aspx), it contains a lot of great tips and resources.

Comment: The question is, as I got, do I need a different version or simply restyle the current app?

Comment: Re-styling an existing site makes no sense. Go with a Mobile First approach and be careful when using media queries with the so-called "Responsive Web Design" approach - you will find that a lot of non-mobile resources are downloaded whether they are used or not.

Comment: As said, you should detect the client browser and redirect him (assuming you're mvc for instance) to a view using the correct css for that broswer/device.  Let say for instance you got a page with tons of javascript, animation and cherry on the top:  a flash player. This is not very mobile friendly (well at least not for iOS). What to do then ? Best thing is redirect the user to a mobile friendly View, this means without flash etc. This can be done by decting the client device, the link contained in the post show the path on how to do it. Hope it is more clear now.